# Using os.("start ...) with variable file name. python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word

The code:

```
doc.save("AttendanceReportFor"+EventNameSTR+".docx")
os.("start AttendanceReportFor"+EventNameSTR+".docx")
```

Where:

```
EventNameSTR=("Juilie")
```

Results in

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the line

```
os.("start AttendanceReportFor"+EventNameSTR+".docx")
```

Is it possible for the os() to take variables in its command statement?

The expected result is opening the word document in Microsoft Word.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `os.system("start ...")`, not `os.("start ...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you are using : `os.("start AttendanceReportFor"+EventNameSTR+".docx")` which is, as the error says: a syntax error, since you can't use `os.(....)` - you should use :

`os.system(command)` or `subprocess.Popen(args....)`